# mule esb community amazon sqs connector requires enterprise licience

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

Developing an use case to add/retrive messages from SQS queue using mule esb.
used mule community amazon sqs connector.

below is log which I see while running the project.

---

ERROR 2016-04-17 18:36:46,238 [Receiving Thread] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: The Module Amazon SQS requires an Enterprise License. Switch to a Mule-EE runtime to enable it.. Type: class org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.lic.InvalidLicenseException
ERROR 2016-04-17 18:36:46,247 [Receiving Thread] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: The Module Amazon SQS requires an Enterprise License. Switch to a Mule-EE runtime to enable it.
org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.lic.InvalidLicenseException: The Module Amazon SQS requires an Enterprise License. Switch to a Mule-EE runtime to enable it.
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.lic.validator.DefaultValidator.(DefaultValidator.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.lic.LicenseValidatorFactory.getValidator(LicenseValidatorFactory.java:13) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.adapters.SQSConnectorProcessAdapter.checkMuleLicense(SQSConnectorProcessAdapter.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.adapters.SQSConnectorProcessAdapter.initialise(SQSConnectorProcessAdapter.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220) ~[commons-pool-1.6.jar:1.6]
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:397) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:19) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:84) ~[mule-module-devkit-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.devkit.3.7.2.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.java:33) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.sources.ReceiveMessagesMessageSource.run(ReceiveMessagesMessageSource.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
INFO  2016-04-17 18:36:51,009 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext:

---

Please help in providing info whether we can use SQS connector in community version runtime(3.7.0 CE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/amazon-sqs-connector-release-notes) of the SQS connector state:

> Starting with v.4.0.0, the SQS Connector is licensed commercially with Anypoint Platform as with other Select connectors. Prior versions will remain freely available to the community.

So you need to use an older version, like 3.2.0, if you target Mule CE.

EDIT: Here is [where one can find the Studio Plugin and Maven JAR for 3.2.0](https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/mule/modules/mule-module-sqs/3.2.0/)